# Dynamically calling nested functions based on arguments

Tags: python, nested, closures

If I have the following Python class:

```
class Test(object):
    funcs = {
        "me"    : "action",
        "action": "action",
        "say"   : "say",
        "shout" : "say"
    }

    def dispatch(self, cmd):
        def say:
            print "Nested Say"

        def action:
            print "Nested Action"

        # The line below gets the function name as a string,
        # How can I call the nested function based on the string?
        Test.funcs.get(cmd, "say")
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
>>> Test().dispatch("me")
Nested Action
>>> Test().dispatch("say")
Nested Say
```

Any suggestions as to how I can go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
def register(dict_, *names):
    def dec(f):
        m_name = f.__name__
        for name in names:
            dict_[name] = m_name
        return f
    return dec

class Test(object):

    commands = {}

    @register(commands, 'foo', 'fu', 'fOo')
    def _handle_foo(self):
        print 'foo'

    @register(commands, 'bar', 'BaR', 'bAR')
    def _do_bar(self):
        print 'bar'

    def dispatch(self, cmd):
        try:
            return getattr(self, self.commands[cmd])()
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            # Command doesn't exist. Handle it somehow if you want to
            # The AttributeError should actually never occur unless a method gets 
            # deleted from the class
```

Now, the class exposes a `dict` whose keys are commands for testing membership. All the methods and the dictionary are created only once.

```
t = Test()

if 'foo' in t.commands:
    t.dispatch('foo')

for cmd in t.commands:
    # Obviously this will call each method with multiple commands dispatched to it once
    # for each command
    t.dispatch(cmd)
```

Etc.

Comment: +1. Looks like you beat me to it :). I was going to suggest something similar. I'd add one little thing which is a second parameter to `register` that will be a list of names the function can be called as using "dispatch". This would remove the hard `handle_*` naming requirement and allow multiple names for the same method as required by the original questioner.

Comment: 'dict' should be 'dict_' in the first line of the 'dec' method, right?

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim. Excellent ideas. Implemented. @mshsayem. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Cool. This is a lot more `DRY` than the version into the post. :)

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim I don't know if it's more DRY since now I have to manually provide a command dispatch but it's definitely more flexible.

Comment: I think it is since otherwise, you'd name the function and somewhere far away repeat its name multiple times in a dictionary.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim. That's a good point. I wasn't considering multiple commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test(object):

    def dispatch(self):
        def say():
            print "Nested Say"

        def action():
            print "Nested Action"

        funcs = {
            "me"    : action,
            "action": action,
            "say"   : say,
            "shout" : say
        }

        Test.funcs.get(cmd, say)()
```

Or, keeping your current structure:

```
class Test(object):

    funcs = {
        "me"    : "action",
        "action": "action",
        "say"   : "say",
        "shout" : "say"
        }

    def dispatch(self, cmd):
        def say():
            print "Nested Say"

        def action():
            print "Nested Action"

        locals()[Test.funcs.get(cmd, "say")]()
```

I find this design a bit odd, though.  Why should the class-level dict know about dispatch's local functions?

Comment: I know I could do that, but I wanted to keep them as a "class level" attribute so I can access them in other locations in the code, and to avoid instantiating the dictionary every time I call that method.

Comment: @Mike, the functions aren't class level methods as you have them defined. They're inner functions of the `dispatch` method. The dictionary will only be defined when the class is first created but the inner functions will be recreated each time the `dispatch` function runs.

Comment: I want them exposed as class levels so other classes can check if any given command is available by doing `Test.funcs.keys()`.  This way I don't need to instantiate a large hash on every call of the `dispatch` method.  Eventually the methods will make use of instance variables, so I can't just make them instance methods, as the class level hash won't have reference to them.  If you can recommend a better approach, I'd be glad to have my eyes opened.